# What do the numbers next to the achievements mean?

Tags: pc, overwatch

Next to each achievement in Overwatch there's a little number in a circle, what does that mean?

[image: The numbers, what do they mean?!]

Comment: Based on Blizzard's other games, I'd say "Achievement Points", but I'm not sure where your total store is displayed.

Comment: its the value associated with the achievement. the achievement score you unlock. Blizzard have utilised this mechanic as early as world of warcraft, where they first started using achievements.

Comment: This sounds like it is a platform-dependent question. Might want to add the PC tag, if that's the platform you're on, or at least specify the platform in the question body.

Comment: I didn't think it was platform-dependant at first, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number signifies the amount of "Achievement Points" the achievement is worth. The amount of points directly corresponds with the Achievement's difficulty.

As of right now I cannot find a way to see all achievement points accrued. I don't like the current achievement menu; it shows you your 6 most recently earned achievements but you have no way of reading a description for them unless you find them on the drop down list.
I would say achievement points are mainly for personal satisfaction; think of them as a reward for doing certain things. Some people may not feel like they have 'completed' a game until all achievements are unlocked. They give players something to use as a goal.

Comment: Is there any way to see an account's total points? Does it do anything?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer As of right now I cannot find a way to see all achievement points accrued. I don't like the current achievement menu; it shows you your 6 most recently earned achievements but you have no way of reading a description for them unless you find them on the drop down list.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I would say achievement points are mainly for personal satisfaction; think of them as a reward for doing certain things. Some people may not feel like they have 'completed' a game until all achievements are unlocked. They give players something to use as a goal.

Comment: Could you add that into the answer?

Comment: If you're playing on Xbox, those point amounts match up with the Gamerscore, so you can see the total by checking your profile for Overwatch achievements. No dice on PlayStation or PC, though.

Comment: first four lines make a good answer. The rest is your personal complaint and speculation, and we do not want that in answers. -1

Comment: @Jeremy Avalon, playstation uses an entirely differant metric that is not mesearable in value (bronze, silver or gold), and the PC achievement score is viewable through accessing your battle.net account(as per the achievement system that was put in place with WoW:WotLK).

Comment: @Timelord64 This question is about Overwatch, not World of Warcraft.

Comment: @JeremyAvalon, to clarify, I am talking about the mechanic of the game, which was *first introduced* with world of warcraft, which can share the same accou t as your overwatch much like how multiple games show up in your steam account.